# Rspec Net::SMTPServerBusy: 454 4.7.1: Relay access denied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, integration-testing

I'm trying to test registration emails (sent with devise), and I keep getting the error:

```
Net::SMTPServerBusy: 454 4.7.1 <model_spec@example.com>: Relay access denied
```

I'm running Rails 3.2.11 with Capybara, and I have (temporarily) chopped my spec_helper.rb and test.rb files down to the bare minimum, still getting the error above.

#### spec_helper.rb:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'spork'

Spork.prefork do
  ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
  require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
  require 'rspec/rails'
  require 'rspec/autorun'
  require 'capybara/rspec'
  Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

  RSpec.configure do |config|
    config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
    config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false
  end
end

Spork.each_run do
  FactoryGirl.reload
end
```

#### test.rb:

```
Upficial::Application.configure do
  config.whiny_nils = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test
end
```

The test itself is very straightforward:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do
  it "sends a confirmation email" do
    @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user, email: "model_spec@example.com", username: "model_spec")
    @user.send_confirmation_instructions
    ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last.to.should == [@user.email]
  end
end
```

I get the same result whether I run with guard/spork or with 'rspec spec/models/user_spec.rb'; the test always fails with

```
Net::SMTPServerBusy: 454 4.7.1 <model_spec@example.com>: Relay access denied
```

Any idea on what configurations should be changed, if any?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your mail server is not configured to accept mail for `*@example.com`. It is refusing to relay email for that domain.

You could add that domain to your mailserver as a valid delivery target, but since this is a test environment, you should probably set your environment to use the test mechanism for emails:

```
# config/environments/test.rb

config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test
```

This will cause emails to be put into `ActionMailer.deliveries` rather than actually sent to your mailserver, so you can inspect and test against their presence and contents.

If `ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method` is *not* `:test`, then it won't work properly; you can test it from a console (via `rails console test`) to see if it is actually `:test` or not. If it's not, find out where it's being overridden and fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Please have a look at my test.rb file above, which includes the line config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test.  Are you suggesting that I put that line elsewhere?

Comment: Do you perhaps have some mailer gem somewhere that is hijacking ActionMailer's deliver stuff and replacing it with its own?

Comment: I've tried stripping the gemfile down to a pretty bare minimum, so I don't think it has to do with conflicting gems.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Try `rails console test` and try inspecting ActionMailer and its configurations; see if you can figure out why it's trying to talk to a mailserver rather than using the test stubs.

Comment: Thanks, I got to poking around in the test console, and saw that ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method was :smtp.  So I did a search for where that was being set, and it was in initializers/mail.rb as well as environments/test.rb.  Looks like the former was overriding the latter, so I commented it out and all is well!  Thanks!

Comment: Also Chris if you can incorporate my above comment into your original answer I can mark it as accepted and hand you the bounty.  Thanks for the lead and jogging some critical thought!